# To which block of the periodic table does helium belong?

Tags: periodic-table

According to quite a few books I have read, helium belongs to the *p-block* with reasoning along the lines of "*it's an inert gas, so let's clump it together with other noble gases which are in the **p-block**.*"

However, on Wikipedia, helium is classified as an *s-block* element which, to me, makes sense because the last (or so-called "differentiating") electron that is added to helium will occupy an **s** sub-shell.

But my teachers are adamant that helium is a *p-block* element, and the fact that our textbook covers helium under the chapter "*The p-block Elements*" just gives them more reinforcement of that idea.

So: is helium an *s-* or a *p-block* element? Could someone provide concrete reasons for and against the block selection?

Comment: It is a noble gas with no p electrons. Another example of a dumb arbitrary classification for little gain in understanding.

Comment: What Jon says. You've got *reason* behind you, your teachers only have their faith in a stupid text book. Stand up to them!

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/block-on-the-periodic-table

Comment: Technically it's an s-block, but follow what your teacher wants if you wanna pass.

Comment: Here(in textbook), helium is classified in p-block for **sake of ease** in studying its properties, as helium is noble gas, where all noble gas are considered in p-block. On other side, if we classify helium in s-block it is only noble gas in s-block.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Blocks in the periodic table should not be mixed up with groups (like noble gases). The reason why Helium is considered a *noble* gas is because its outermost (and at the same time only) shell is fully occupied by its 2 electrons. When you look at the electron configurations in the PTE you can see that the first element which happens to have an occupied p-orbital is boron. Due to this fact boron also has to be the first p-block element, since the block definition is as follows:

> An element belongs to the block x, if the electron, which is added in comparison to the previous element (by atomic number), is in an orbital of type x in the ground-state electron configuration of that element.

Or the fast explanation: Why should helium be considered a p-block element, if it doesn't even have any electron in a p-orbital or any shell including a p-orbital?

Comment: Jup. One electron in the *1s* shell also doesn't make hydrogen an alkali metal.

Answer (score 6):

Helium is an s-block element with properties like those of the p-block noble gases.

In a periodic table more concerned with chemical behaviour you're likely to see He in the p-block.

In a table more concerned with showing the filling of electron shells you're likely to see He in the s-block.

The optimal solution is to show He in the s-block but to colour it as a noble gas or a p-block element.