# The ambiguity regarding aufbau principle

Tags: electronic-configuration, atoms

According to a Blog https://ericscerri.blogspot.com/2012/06/trouble-with-using-aufbau-to-find.html
written by Dr.Eric Scerri,

> On moving from the $\ce{Sc^3+}$ ion to that of $\ce{Sc^2+}$ it is plain to see that the additional electron enters a 3d orbital and not a 4s orbital as the sloppy scheme dictates. Similarly on moving from this ion to the $\ce{Sc^1+}$ ion the additional electron enters a 4s orbital as it does in finally arriving at neutral scandium atom or Sc.

According to it, the last electron enters the 4s orbital. Why is Scandium a d-block element, then?

Comment: Please *do* use MathJax where it is *appropriate* (e.g. to typeset chemical formulae using `$\ce{...}$`) and *don't* use it where it is *inappropriate* (e.g. to place emphasis on text by simply wrapping it in `$...$`). Please consider reading [FAQ: How can I format math/chemistry expressions on Chemistry Stack Exchange?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/86/16683).

Comment: Is the configuration of Sc [Ar] 4s2 4p1?

Comment: @Poutnik,it is indeed,[Ar]4s2 3d1,and as per the blog,the last electron enters 4s,so why it isn't a s block element?

Comment: Why do you think element blocks are named according to where the last formally added electron enters?

Comment: @Poutnik,isn't it the case?if not please explain me correct information

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate (in effect) of [Blocks on the Periodic Table](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/13958/block-on-the-periodic-table).

Comment: If the last electron place principle had been applied, the second f block of actinoids would have been destroyed as there is 6d-5f energy switching in the first half of actinoids. The first actinoids behaving more like d-block transition metals. E.g. There is no lanthanoid with oxidation number +VI like uranium, which may remind rather Cr-Mo-W.

Comment: @Poutnik,so what is the correct reason of the naming of blocks in periodic table?

Comment: In contrary to some other Q/A or forum sites, answers on CH SE site are figuratively paid by the user's own effort. When you ask, you are supposed to search and thoroughly think about the topic and to provide explicit compact summary of partial answers or at least ideas or thoughts you have got until then. Effort not shown may be considered as effort not done and such a question may be closed.

Comment: @Poutnik,I am extremely sorry for that,If i had not put enough efforts on understanding the topic,or the concept,but I have searched a lot that why are elements categorized in block as S,P,D,F,but Every where,there is reasoned to follow aufbau rule and subshell which is filled last in the electronic configuration determines its block,,but why is this so,aufbau principle correctly describes overall configuration,but what was reason behind accepting the aufbau for dividing into blocks,what does the blocks of element indicate,their valence electron?if so then it is incorrect in case of scandium?

Comment: @Poutnik,thanks a lot,after a Bit surfing and thinking over your comment again, I got the answer,Those are the DIFFERENTIATING electrons which decide the block of the element in periodic table

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I got the answer after a short surfing,The answer to this question is pretty simple,the blocks are made ,by taking the basis of classification as the Differentiating electrons,wherever the differentiating electron exists in a subshell,that is the block of that Element.
*Differentiating electrons* simply mean that the electron which differentiates the element's Electronic configuration from the preceeding element's Electronic Configuration,
for example
Though the last electron enters in 4s subshell of Scandium atom, it is a 3d electron which makes the difference between the atom and the previous one.Since Ca is $[Ar] 4s^2$ and Sc is $[Ar]3d^1 4s^2$